# How long does a secret URL need to be?

Tags: web-application, web-service, network-scanners, python, entropy

I'm currently creating a small service where users can upload images (just a free time project). The images are either private, public (unlisted) or public (listed).

Now I'm wondering for public unlisted content how long the URL should be. So if a user `foo` uploads `bar.png`, I would generate a random name for it, e.g. with python:

```
import random

def generate_name(file_extension: str = ".png", random_chars=12):
    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    chars = chars + chars.lower() + "0123456789"
    r = random.SystemRandom()
    random_part = ''.join([r.choice(chars) for i in range(random_chars)])
    return random_part + file_extension
```

So the name is random, not only a hash of the input.

If I use 12 characters, there are `62**12` possible values. Assuming the web service gets used way more than a hobby project will every be, let's say I'd have `10**6` users uploading each `10**4` photos, each of them public (unlisted). This would make `10**10` elements.

This would mean for each photo there are `10**11` elements which did not get assigned (`62**12 / 10**10`). Assuming an attacker can check `10**4` URLs per second, they would in average need `10**11 / 10**4s` = 115 days to to find one by chance. Of course, by chance the attacker could either find one way earlier or way later.

Is the reasoning correct? How many URLs can be checked per second by a private attacker? (I've heard that private people scanned the whole IPv4 range in a short time)

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is generally correct, the base math is indeed
`(charset_size**code_length) / guesses_per_second` (where `**` is exponentiation). For the sake of completeness (I see you already took most of this into account), there are some things one should factor in:

- How fast is your web server? This would limit how fast they can check, at least currently.
- Does your server implement any monitoring or rate limiting? If you limit users per IP, how many different IP addresses do you expect they can get access to?
- For how many years should the data be secure?
- Does the attacker "win" if they guess a specific secret URL, or *anyone's* secret URL? In case of the latter, you need to factor in the number of URLs you expect to exist after years of running the service (as you did).
- Is the server using a secure random (your code looks good).

Perhaps slightly out of scope of this question, but there are also some general security considerations:

- Does a request take longer if a few characters are guessed correctly (because the database then needs to do more lookups in the indexed field) and might an attacker be able to guess it (almost) character-by-character?
- Secrets in URLs are generally a bad idea: they may be stored in browser history, corporate proxy logs, visible while shoulder surfing, and may be sent to third parties through the `Referer` header. The only one of these you can really prevent is setting a `Referrer-Policy`, but relying on web server configuration for security seems fragile.
  Of course, it may be unavoidable in this case and I doubt there exists an equally convenient alternative method. It's just generally good to be aware that secrets in URLs are not a very reliable security mechanism.

To answer the specific question about

> How many URLs can be checked per second by a private attacker?

Let's say they're willing to spend some money to get a gigabit connection (125MB/s) and that it takes 2KB of traffic to check whether a given URL exists, then assuming no server limitations, you're looking at about 125e6/2e3≈**63k requests per second**. Since VPSes with a gigabit uplink are very cheap, I think it's fair to assume that any motivated individual can run a bunch of these in parallel. Bandwidth costs will also probably go down in the future as they have in the past.